# How can I decode token group extension data from a token-2022 mint?

Tags: token-2022

The getTokenMetadata helper is great for decoding metadata for token-2022 mints: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/5667/files#diff-e7f398b453e53424bf65972e879155e4709f218643c807c90f8cec60cdef118aR70

I'm trying to do something similar for the group extension, to check whether a mint is part of a collection. But I'm having trouble figuring out a way to decode this. It also looks like the extension type isn't available in @solana/spl-token: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/8b22d759fef30795eff99385f15ae1c4380eeb90/token/js/src/extensions/extensionType.ts#L63

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry about that, this is currently a work-in-progress, just created this issue https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/6175 to address it. There is an existing JS library just for the token-group extension, so you could use that to decode the token groups in the meantime. Or better yet, submit a PR to add the support!